# how to use crontab to run scripts so that they are executed one after the other on separate days?

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos, cron

I have 3 shell scripts which I want to run in order in separate days. how can i do that with crontab?

for example i have these 3 scripts: `test1 test2 test3`
today is Monday. script `test1` is executed at 12 o'clock.
tomorrow is Tuesday. script `test2` is executed at 12 o'clock.
Wednesday, `test3`.
Thursday, `test1`.
Friday, `test2`.
and so on.

(if any further information is needed please let me know in comments so i will add to question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to run a script daily, and let it keep track of which script to run. something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# find my name
me="${0##*/}"
# make sure the counter file exists.
counter="/var/run/$me"
if [[ ! -f "$counter" ]] ; then
  echo "1" >"$counter"
fi
maxcount=3
 
pick="$(cat  "$counter")"
nextpick=$(( pick + 1 ))
[[ $nextpick -gt $maxcount ]] && nextpick=1
echo "$nextpick" > "$counter"

case $pick in
  1) test1;break;;
  2) test2;break;;
  3) test3;break;;
  *) echo "Invalid pick: $pick" >&2; exit 1;;
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it helped you.

Comment: so i should copy this to a file and run it every day?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "... run a script daily ..."